# Update many fields in collection with using $in in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have tried following query in mongodb but i got

> "the update operation document must contain atomic operators"

error then i have done some changes in query but still same error showing

```
db.admin_config.updateMany({ $set: {
  "config_values.abc": {
    "entity_value": 10,
    "is_active": 0,
    "is_updatable": true
  }
}
},
{"party_code": { $in: ["3103"] }})
.projection({})
.sort({_id:-1})
.limit(100)
```

Comment: you have passed the argument in wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

**Change your code with this.**

```
db.admin_config.updateMany({"party_code": { $in: ["3103"] }} , { $set: {
  "config_values.abc": {
    "entity_value": 10,
    "is_active": 0,
    "is_updatable": true
  }
}})
```

Comment: so, is the operation order matter?